# Equivariant rank theorem.

Tags: smooth-manifolds, group-actions, equivariant-maps

I was reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1416354/340973) that explains why

$$\phi :O_{n}\times H\rightarrow GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$$ $$\phi(B,A)=BA$$ is a diffeomorphism. Here $O_{n}$ is the orthogonal group and $H$ is the group of all upper triangular matices.

The answer uses the following theorem.

> **Theorem 7.25** (Equivariant Rank Theorem). Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds and let $G$ be a Lie group. Suppose $F : M \to N$ is a
> smooth map that is equivariant with respect to a transitive smooth
> $G$-action on $M$ and any smooth $G$-action on $N$ . Then $F$ has
> constant rank. Thus, if $F$ is surjective, it is a smooth submersion;
> if it is injective, it is a smooth immersion; and if it is bijective,
> it is a diffeomorphism.

but in the answer, he just finds **one** action on $O_n \times H$ and another **one** on $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that the map is equivariant to conclude. But the theorem says that to conclude the map should be equivariant for any action on $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ no? What am I understanding wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quotation is from my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.* It's a good illustration of the pitfalls of using the word "any" as a quantifier.

What I meant by "any smooth $G$-action on $N$" was "an arbitrary (not necessarily transitive) smooth $G$-action on $N$." I definitely did not mean "every smooth $G$-action on $N$." I expect that except in very trivial cases, there won't be any maps that are equivariant with respect to a transitive action on $M$ and *every* action on $N$.

Comment: Thank you. It is clear now!